# is there a .innerXML?

Tags: javascript, xml, ajax, dom

i'd like to ask if anyone here is familiar wif xml who can give me some help...
http://www.plognow.com/xml/login.xml
and i hv a little function tht i use to break it up...

```
function dialogXML(varName,url){
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
        r[varName]=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }else{
        r[varName]=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    r[varName].onreadystatechange=function(){
        if (r[varName].readyState==4 && r[varName].status==200){
            var rep=r[varName].responseXML.getElementsByTagName('box')[0];
            var title=rep.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].nodeValue;
            var content=rep.getElementsByTagName('content')[0].nodeValue;
            createDialog(title,content);
        }
    }
    r[varName].open('GET',url,true);
    r[varName].send();
}
```

well i'm not sure how XMLDOM works, but can i retrieve the inwards of one tag?(all the childs subchilds etc)like u'd do in **innerHTML**. thanks!

Comment: The URL you provided is password protected.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) to manipulate XML documents as well not just HTML documents. HTML documents are XML documents.

```
if (r[varName].readyState==4 && r[varName].status==200){
    var xml = r[varName].responseXML;            
    var rep = $("box:first", xml);
    var title = $("title:first", rep).text();
    var content= $("content:first", rep).text();
    createDialog(title, content);
}
```

Comment: HTML documents are not XML documents

Answer (score 0):

If your question is how to retrieve xml tree structure then the answer is : using `responseXML` property of `r[varName]`.

Comment: what i'm trying to do is to is to get whats inside "<"title">" and " <"content">", which inside involves a bit of tags, which node value doesn't quite work, since they regard it as childs. what i want to do is to take thw whole "innerHTML" of the title and content tags

Comment: You can use `r[varName].responseXML.getElementsByTagName("title/content")[val1].childNodes[val2].value` based on the location of your title/content tags.